# Is malloc-ing a char the same as referencing a char array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I think I have got my head mostly around the difference, but if I am correct, then this should be correct also:

1.)

```
char *string1 = (char*) malloc(runtime_determined_number);
```

2.)

```
char string2val[runtime_determined_number];
char *string2 = &string2val;
```

Here I would expect string1 and string2 to be the same, is this the case?

Comment: To be the same in what sense? Also, the cast in the first sample is wrong, and the pointer types in the second one mismatch.

Comment: H2CO3: There's no pointer-type-mismatch - it's weird, and I wouldn't write the '&', but it's valid.

Comment: This is tagged as a 'C' question.  I don't believe that C allows a declaration like `char string2val[runtime_determined_number];` You could use a *compile time* symbol there, but not a runtime variable.  I found elsewhere that this is bad in C89, but ok in C99.  I guess I'm too old.

Comment: I've said it before, and H2CO3 said it above but somewhat opaquely. So, here we go again: [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: I meant same in the sense that both fragments of code achieve the same goal.

Comment: @MatthewHaworth example of usage will help to get the good answer

Comment: @Dougall: `&string2val` is a pointer to an array of char, but `string2` is a pointer to char. The pointer types do not match. The automatic conversion of array to pointer does not happen when the array is the operand of `&`.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I think effect is correct, but there is a pointer type mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string1` and `string2` are not pointed to the same memory area

`string1` is a pointer pointing to a `char` array allocated dynamically with `malloc`

`string2` is a pointer pointing to a `char` array allocated statically

Comment: Does the `runtime_determined_number` not make `string2`'s allocation dynamic?

Comment: @MatthewHaworth since C99 it's allowed to define static array with runtime var as you did in your example but this is still static allocation and not dynamic allocation. The dynamic allocation memory could be free later in your code with free() but this is not possible for static memories

Comment: The definitions shown for `string2val` and `string2` may appear inside a function or outside. If they appear inside a function as shown except with the type mismatch corrected, the storage duration is automatic, not static.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I missed that in my last comment

Comment: @MatthewHaworth Refer to the `EricPostpischil` answer it complete my answer

Comment: Sorry, what is the type mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

They both point to uninitialized blocks of memory of the same length. So in that respect they are the same, yes.

Note that in case 1, you are responsible for `free`ing the memory once you're finished. And in case 2, you can't safely return the pointer from a function as the memory will go out of scope on exit.

Answer (score 0):

They are similar in that they have the same type and have at least `runtime_determined_number` bytes allocated for them.

They are different in that:

1. the first version requires an explicit `free()` to avoid a memory leak;
2. the lifetime of the two objects may or may not be the same.

Note that the second version is only valid in [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99), since it makes use of a variable-length array.

Answer (score 0):

Using `malloc` you are asking the OS for memory during runtime. If `malloc` succeeded you are able to work with the allocated memory. You must deallocate this memory later on!
In your second part you are creating a `char`-array and then assign its address to a pointer. In this case the memory is taken from the `stack` and will be `free`d automatically when the array goes out of scope.
Your `char*`s won't be the same as they will be pointing to different locations in memory. There is aminor chance they contain the same garbage as you have not initialized them...